# Email twitter updates

Tags: twitter

Is there any way to email status updates to twitter, rather than having to login and post them? For instance can I email mytwitter@somedomain.com and the subject becomes the twitter message.

I realise what the security implications would be for this, just wondering if anyone knows of a site or app that has overcome them.

Comment: this one's a bit long-winded ... http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/send-twitter-updates-email-mobile-phone-without-sms/2955/

Comment: Wrong site. Try http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tweeterism.com/twittermail-update-twitter-using-email/ - this will give you everything you need but there are other options available

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

http://tweetymail.com/faq#what

> Tweetymail is a complete email interface to Twitter. It provides three
>   powerful sets of features for interacting with Twitter via email:
>
> - Email-based Twitter app: tweetymail allows you to use most of
>     Twitter's features by sending a quick email. You can tweet, view your
>     timeline, send and reply to direct messages, follow users, and more.
>     It's just like a desktop or mobile app for Twitter - except that it
>     works anywhere you have access to your email!
> - Automatic email alerts: tweetymail provides quick and easy email
>     alerts for Twitter. You can automatically receive mentions, create
>     Twitter searches, receive tweets from a Twitter list, and receive your
>     Twitter timeline. tweetymail email alerts are really fast and often
>     arrive in less than 2 minutes. Best of all, you can retweet and reply
>     to tweets directly from your inbox!
> - Awesome Twitter notifications: Let's face it - the standard
>     notifications that Twitter sends for new followers and direct messages
>     are not very useful. tweetymail can replace these notifications with
>     detailed emails that contain links to take action immediately.